# How to Play system beep sound programatically in iPhone?Is it possible to play system sound without adding it to bundle resources

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

Is it possible to play system beep alert sound.I do not want to add the sound file to my resource bundle and i want to access the apple system sounds and play it wherever needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1103);

to vibrate

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

For list of sounds

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices

Comment: will apple accept these enum,are you sure apple will not reject the app if we add sound id from these enum

Comment: I cannot say, sorry. If it is a concern download one of the many free sounds and use that.