# how can i play a notification sound in IOS

Tags: trigger.io

Can someone give an example of playing a sound (eg, a notification beep) triggered via javascript or forge?  I have tried everything, but it all fails on IOS!!

`if (newTweets) { playSound('beep.wav'); }`

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is driving me insane!!!

Cheers.

Comment: Why are you posting JavaScript code for iOS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Play system beep sound programatically in iPhone?Is it possible to play system sound without adding it to bundle resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711983/how-to-play-system-beep-sound-programatically-in-iphoneis-it-possible-to-play-s)

Comment: this was meant to be tagged for trigger.io, hence the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [media module](https://trigger.io/modules/media/current/docs/index.html) by Trigger.io to your app.

Looking at the documentation, the following code should do the trick:

```
forge.file.getLocal("music.mp3", function (file) {
  forge.media.createAudioPlayer(file, function (player) {
    player.play();
  });
});
```